# How to delete a fixed number of items from end of list in python

Tags: python, list

If you have a list

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Is there a pythonic way to delete a defined number of items from the end of a list.

EG (pseudocode):

```
removeFromend(myList, 3)
print myList

>>>[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list slicing, which I think is the most pythonic way of doing it:

```
end_trimm = 3
myList = myList[:-end_trimm]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mutate the list, setting a slice to an empty list is equivalent to deleting those indices.

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

myList[-3:] = []

myList
Out[16]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

This works in cases where you can't simply rebind `myList` to a new list, e.g. you pass your list to a function and want that function to mutate your list.

Answer (score 1):

`del`ing the slice is the direct approach

```
>>> myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> del myList[-3:]
>>> myList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

The `-3` means the slice starts 3 from the end, So the general form is `del myList[-n:]`